# WPF NotifyPropertyChange from different thread

Tags: c#, wpf, refresh

I have my VM implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface. I created another thread T for populating a list that I bind to Xaml. After list is populated, I call PropertyChanged in thread T, and my UI got refreshed correctly.

My question is in what case I would need to use Dispatcher? Why I don't need to use Dispatcher in my case?  I thought Dispatcher is used when the code in other thread want to notify the changes to the UI thread by enqueuing the changes to the UI refresh queue, such as adding items to  ObservableCollection from another thread, and UI thread will then pull data from the queue.

```
private List<string> _ListData;

public List<String> ListData
{
    get
    {
        if (_ListData == null)
              Initialise( () => ListData = ReturnSlow());

        return _ListData;
    }
    set { _ListData = value; }
}

private List<string> ReturnSlow()
{
    List<string> Test = new List<string>();

    Test.Add("1");
    Test.Add("2");

    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    return Test;

 }

    public void Initialise(Action initialiser)
    {
        Task t = new Task(() =>
        {
            initialiser();
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ListData"));
        });

        t.Start();
    }
```

Comment: You have to use it only if your collection would be an ObservableCollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app has a main UI thread (usually `ManagedThreadId==1`). If you want to update the UI from an event that gets pull on some other thread you must use the dispatcher. A useful test here is the `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` method that returns true if code is on UI thread and false if on some other thread.  A typical call looks something like:

```
using System.Windows.Threading; // For Dispatcher.

if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) {
    network_links.Add(new NetworkLinkVM(link, start_node, end_node));
}
else {
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(()=>{
        network_links.Add(new NetworkLinkVM(link, start_node, end_node));
    }));
}
```

If you're in the main window you can use:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...
```

If you're in someother context eg a view model then use:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
```

**Invoke vs BeginInvoke**
Use `Invoke` if you want the current thread to wait until the UI thread has processed the dispatch code or `BeginInvoke` if you want current thread to continue without waiting for operation to complete on UI thread.

**MessageBox, Dispatchers and Invoke/BeginInvoke:**
`Dispatcher.Invoke` will block your thread until the MessageBox is dismissed.
`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` will allow your thread code to continue to execute while the UI thread will block on the MessageBox call until its dismissed.

**CurrentDispatcher vs Current.Dispatcher!**
Be ware of `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` as my understanding of this is that is will return a Dispatcher for the current thread not the UI thread.  Generally are you interested in the dispatcher on the UI thread - `Application.Current.Dispatcher` always returns this.

**Additional note:**
If you are finding you are having to check dispatcher CheckAccess often then a useful helper method is:

```
public void DispatchIfNecessary(Action action) {
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    else
        action.Invoke();
}
```

Which can be called as:

```
DispatchIfNecessary(() => {
    network_links.Add(new NetworkLinkVM(link, start_node, end_node));
});
```

Comment: but in my case, why I don't need to use Dispatcher?

Comment: In your specific case, where you're relying entirely on INotifyPropertyChanged to notify the controls of changes to your model - then no, you don't need the Dispatcher. However, if you expose any properties in your VM that are not thread safe (such as the ObservableCollection<T>, or WritableBitmap, etc), you may need to use the Dispatcher to invoke their methods on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: @olitee, please see my edit. What do you mean by thread safe, such as in ObservableCollection? How does INotifyPropertyChanged mechanism work together with the refresh queue in the UI window?

Comment: @YaelB, can you please explain more on how Dispatcher works with the refresh queue for the UI window? and How INotifyProepertyChanged notify the UI from different thread?